# openshift installation error on centos 7

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have install the openshift in centos 7.

Installed the prerequisite and then installing the openshift via this command.

atomic-openshift-installer install

getting this error..  Please guide how to solve the same.

[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: oo_lb_to_config
There was a problem fetching the required information. Please see /tmp/ansible.log for details.

tail -f /tmp/ansible.log

2018-07-21 12:36:47,139 p=23956 u=root |  skipping: [10.142.0.2]
2018-07-21 12:36:47,160 p=23956 u=root |  TASK [openshift_version : Set openshift_version for rpm installation] ************************************************************************************

---

2018-07-21 12:36:47,209 p=23956 u=root |  included: /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/roles/openshift_version/tasks/check_available_rpms.yml for 10.142.0.2
2018-07-21 12:36:47,233 p=23956 u=root |  TASK [openshift_version : Get available origin version] **************************************************************************************************

---

2018-07-21 12:36:47,767 p=23956 u=root |  fatal: [10.142.0.2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.142.0.2 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recen
t call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aWcbKG/ansible_module_repoquery.py\", line 642, in \r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aWcbKG/ansible_module_repoquery.py\", line 632, in main\r\
n    rval = Repoquery.run_ansible(module.params, module.check_mode)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aWcbKG/ansible_module_repoquery.py\", line 588, in run_ansible\r\n    results = repoquery.repoquery()\r
\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aWcbKG/ansible_module_repoquery.py\", line 547, in repoquery\r\n    rval = self._repoquery_cmd(repoquery_cmd, True, 'raw')\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aWcbKG/ansible_module_re
poquery.py\", line 385, in _repoquery_cmd\r\n    returncode, stdout, stderr = _run(cmds)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_aWcbKG/ansible_module_repoquery.py\", line 356, in _run\r\n    stderr=subprocess.P
IPE)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 711, in **init**\r\n    errread, errwrite)\r\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py\", line 1327, in _execute_child\r\n    raise c
hild_exception\r\nOSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
2018-07-21 12:36:47,770 p=23956 u=root |  PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

---

2018-07-21 12:36:47,770 p=23956 u=root |  10.142.0.2                 : ok=24   changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
2018-07-21 12:36:47,770 p=23956 u=root |  localhost                  : ok=12   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
2018-07-21 12:36:47,770 p=23956 u=root |  INSTALLER STATUS *****************************************************************************************************************************************

---

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore this warning:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: oo_lb_to_config 
There was a problem fetching the required information. Please see 
/tmp/ansible.log for details.
```

All this is saying is that you have not defined a load balancer (haproxy).  So your DNS needs to point to the masters or your are installing an haproxy manually.

tail -f /tmp/ansible.log

2018-07-21 12:36:47,139 p=23956 u=root | skipping: [10.142.0.2] 2018-07-21 12:36:47,160 p=23956 u=root | TASK [openshift_version : Set openshift_version for rpm installation] ************************************************************************************

2018-07-21 12:36:47,209 p=23956 u=root | included: /usr/share/ansible/openshift-ansible/roles/openshift_version/tasks/check_available_rpms.yml for 10.142.0.2 2018-07-21 12:36:47,233 p=23956 u=root | TASK [openshift_version : Get available origin version] **************************************************************************************************

I had a similiar problem.  It was due to an inconsistent setup of all of the nodes, having different versions of the rpms.  But I have the feeling that this isn't going on here.

Try running the ansible-playbooks with the -vvvv option (the advanced install).  This may help you find what the issue is.